# How erasure of generics "replace" multiple bounds

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I read that during the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.
But, i can't understand, **isn't it redundant to specify the interface that the type parameter needs to implement**. For example:

```
public class Box<T extends Something,Seralizable,Cloneable>
```

If erasure replaces `T` inside the class `Box` with `Something` (Class reference), doesn't it mean interfaces: `Seralizable,Cloneable` must be implemented by Something class, so only me it's feel redundant to specify `Seralizable,Cloneable` interfaces? In addition what happens if only interfaces are mentioned inside the diamonds, does by default `T` consider as *`Object`* reference?

I will be glad for one example for Generic Class and one example for Generic Method (if multiple extends exist in generics method).

Comment: If your question is "How erasure of generics “replace” multiple bounds?", then the answer is on the second line of your question: "replaces each with its **first** bound" (emphasis mine), isn't it? If that's not what your question is, then what is it?

Comment: Can't understand what the mean of first bound, does it mean the Class? Since the class is the first one? and if the answer for my questions is yes, which advantage in in specifying the interfaces, if the class that in the upper bound must extend them anyway?

Comment: Also, does multiple bounds relevant to generic method or only for generic class/interfaces?

Comment: If the bounds are `<T extends Foo & Serializable>`, then the **first** bound if Foo. The second one is Serializable. The first is the one that comes first.

Comment: @Eitanos30 he's given you a straightforward answer. The first bound is the bound that appears first. There's nothing more complicated to it than that.

Comment: I'm not thinking it's a joke. As I said in my first comment, I think it's unclear, because the question you ask is answered in your own question, and I'm just wondering what else you might be asking. You wondered what "first" means in this context, and I think I gave you a clear explanation, with an example.

Comment: @Andy Turner, JJB Nizet - let's say i had some diffictult with english and didn't understand the meaning of first. Yes it's seems stupidly i admit, but i also ask,_" and if the answer for my questions is yes, which advantage in in specifying the interfaces, if the class that in the upper bound must extend them anyway?"_  I don't have problem to elaborate my post but if i have enough courage to ask a question that may seems bad, so i really desperate to get help

Comment: @Eitanos30 please, take a breath. You're doing fine :) Hopefully your main confusion has been cleared by JB's example? In terms of specifying interfaces: there is no requirement for the class already to implement an interface. For example, you could say `<T extends YourClass & Serializable>`, where `YourClass` is something that doesn't already implement `Serializable`: this specifies that `T` must be some subclass of `YourClass` which also implements `Serializable`.

Comment: *which advantage in in specifying the interfaces, if the class that in the upper bound must extend them anyway?*: no, it doesn't have to extend them. Take my previous example: if an argument is of type T, and T is defined as `T extends Foo & Serializable`, Foo doesn't have to implement Serializable. What must implement Serializable is the type f the argument. So, for example, if you have `class Bar extends Foo implements Serializable`, it can be passed as argument. If you have `Bar extends Foo`, it can't.

Comment: @Andy Turner,JB Nizet, First of all, thanks for the concern, I'm cool, thanks. Only a little bit _broken_ from programming :(  I had elaborated my question,and i see you both preceded me in your comments.I must confess,that both comments helps me a lot. I didn't think of it alone. _But_, how is it possible that Foo/YourClass  reference will be able to run _Serializable_ method (let's say only for the discussion  Serlializble interface has method/s), **if Foo/YourClass doesn't implement it?** AFAIK polymorphism won't work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You acutally already answered your question: The erasure is the first bound or Object if the type is not bounded. Let's look at a few examples:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    //  since the first bound is Cloneable, the erasure is Cloneable
    static <T extends Cloneable & Serializable> void doSomething1(T t) {}

    //  since the first bound is Serializable, the erasure is Serializable
    static <T extends Serializable & Cloneable> void doSomething2(T t) {}

    // since T is not bounded, the erasure is Object
    static <T> void doSomething(T t) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    // the type of A is a class, so it has to come first
    // the erasure is A since it comes first
    static <T extends A & Serializable> void doSomething(T t) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    // not possible because the bounds are two classes
    // static <T extends Object & A> void doSomething(T t) {return null;}
}
```

**Since the erasures are different, the methods can have the same name!** But this is totally not recommended and rather confusing because the behavior changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A.doSomething(new Object());  // prints "A"
    A.doSomething(new A());       // prints "B"
}
```

To answer your question after your edit: No, it is not redundant. Specifying the type the type parameter needs to implement gives you access to the methods of the bounds. Let's have a look at the following example:

```
public final class Box<T extends A & Comparable<T>> {
    private T item1;
    private T item2;

    int compare() {
        // this is the compare method of Comparable interface
        return item1.compareTo(item2);
    }
}
```

From the example above you see that `A` doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface. That means that if you just write `Box<T extends A>` you can't compare the two items in your `Box` using the `compareTo` method simply because `A` doesn't implement `Comparable`. If you want your box items to be of class `A` **and** to implement the `Comparable` interface, you need to specify both bounds.

It's not the `A` reference that implements `Comparable` but the `T` reference! Even though the erasure of `T extends A & Comparable<T>` will be `A` the compiler can still perform the cast on a lower level. And this is what's happening here. You can see this, if you inspect the byte code using the `javap` utility where a [checkcast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.checkcast) instruction is used:

```
  int compare();
         ....
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #7                  // Field item1:LA;
         4: checkcast     #13                 // class java/lang/Comparable
         7: aload_0
         8: getfield      #15                 // Field item2:LA;
        11: invokeinterface #18,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/lang/Comparable.compareTo:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        16: ireturn
        ....
```

Comment: thanks. But it's not exactly what i have asked. i asked isn't it redundant to specifiy interfaces if your already specified a class. You can see in the comments for my post that both _Andy Turner'_ and _JB Nizet_ tried to explain me why it isn't redundant. But i comment them about a little issue i found that in my opinion may be problematic, although i'm sure it's mine misunderstanding, i hope they will be able to make things clearer.

Comment: Your question is if you have `Box<T extends ClassA & Serializalbe>` if specifying `Serializable` is redundant?

Comment: Yes, and they both explained me why it isn't. But i didn't understand small part in their's  answer. i prefer not to make _Copy Paste_, so if you want you are more than welcome to look at my comment

Comment: thanks but you wrote exactly what they already wrote. And as i said i have something that i don't understand in their comments. Nevertheless, i will make the _Copy Paste_ (with the suitable changes to your example) from that comment: "how is it possible that **A** reference will be able to run **Comparable** method  if  A class doesn't implement it? AFAIK polymorphism won't work here?"

Comment: @Eitanos30 It's not the `A` reference that implements it but the `T` reference. The compiler is doing the cast on a lower level. I've updated my answer once again.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how to read bytecode (and i tried to understand it from the link you send but it didn't help me). But undoubtedly your answer is clear enough when saying that a down casting is made from reference _A_ to reference _Comparable_ so compareTo method can be run  (hope that was what you meant).