# How does java type erasure treats '?'

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Hopefully, after understanding generic boundaries, i'm trying to understand wildcard upper and lower bounds. my reference is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html
I found there a sentence i can understand: *"The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable;*"
Fields and local variable? can't imagine it. Why such an important source doesn't emphasize it by  a simple example?

I'm trying to understand with which reference java compiler replaces (while erasure) '?'. Maybe i have a big  misunderstanding and any erasure happens (So all the following examples are not relevant).
In the following examples:
1.

```
public static void funcA (List<? extends Number>l)
```

2.

```
public static void funcB(List<? super Integer>l)
```

and is there a difference between second example and the following code:
3.

```
public static <T extends Integer> funcC(List<? extends T>l)
```

And if there any different between example 2 and the following one:
4.

```
public static <T extends Integer> void funcC(List<T>l)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201499/discussion-between-slaw-and-eitanos30).

Comment: *"Can't imagine it"* — Fields: `private List<?> myList;`, local variables: `void test() { List<?> myList; }`.

Answer (score 6):

***Preface:** You've asked a number of questions about type erasure, including in the chat room. While this answer will address this specific question it may answer some of your other questions as well (maybe even some you haven't asked yet).*

***Warning:** This answer is long and the question specifically asked in this post is only directly addressed at the end.*

---

## What is type erasure?

This has been covered quite well in other Q&As so I will simply link to them:

- [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)
- [What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java)
- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

## What are the rules of type erasure?

The rules of type erasure are specified in [§4.6 Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of the *Java Language Specification (JLS)*:

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables). We write `|T|` for the erasure of type `T`. The erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> - The erasure of a parameterized type ([§4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)) `G<T1,...,Tn>` is `|G|`.
> - The erasure of a nested type `T.C` is `|T|.C`.
> - The erasure of an array type `T[]` is `|T|[]`.
> - The erasure of a type variable ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
> - The erasure of every other type is the type itself.
>
> Type erasure also maps the signature ([§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)) of a constructor or method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature `s` is a signature consisting of the same name as `s` and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in `s`.
>
> The return type of a method ([§8.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) and the type parameters of a generic method or constructor ([§8.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4), [§8.8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.4)) also undergo erasure if the method or constructor's signature is erased.
>
> The erasure of the signature of a generic method has no type parameters.

For this answer we should focus on the first and fourth bullet points which say:

> The erasure of a parameterized type ([§4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)) `G<T1,...,Tn>` is `|G|`.

And:

> The erasure of a type variable ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Respectively. In particular, notice how the fourth bullet point only explains the erasure of *type variables*. Why does this matter? I'll come back to that.

### Terminology

Understanding the terms is important to understanding how the rules are applied:

- *Generic class*

  - Specified in [§8.1.2 Generic Classes and Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) of the JLS.
  - A *generic class* is a class which declares one or more *type variables*.
- *Generic interface*

  - Specified in [§9.1.2 Generic Interfaces and Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.2) of the JLS.
  - A *generic interface* is an interface which declares one or more *type variables*.
- *Generic method*

  - Specified in [§8.4.4 Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4) of the JLS.
  - A *generic method* is a method which declares one or more *type variables*.
- *Generic constructor*

  - Specified in [§8.8.4 Generic Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.4) of the JLS.
  - A *generic constructor* is a constructor which declares one or more *type variables*.
- *Type variable*

  - Specified in [§4.4 Type Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) of the JLS.
  - A *type variable* is introduced by a *type parameter* declared on the generic member.
  - The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeVariable) of a *type variable* is: *`{Annotation} TypeIdentifier`*
- *Type parameter*

  - Specified in many sections of the JLS. Every section I linked to for the above terms mentions *type parameters*.
  - A *type parameter* is the declaration of a *type variable*, plus its bounds, on a generic member.
  - The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeParameter) of a *type parameter* is: *`{TypeParameterModifier} TypeIdentifier [TypeBound]`* where *`TypeParameterModifier`* expands into *`Annotation`*.
- *Parameterized type*

  - Specified in [§4.5 Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) of the JLS.
  - A *parameterized type* is the actual use of a *generic class* or *generic interface* with *type arguments*.
- *Type argument*

  - Specified in [§4.5.1 Type Arguments of Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) of the JLS.
  - A *type argument* is the actual type or wildcard used in place of a *type parameter*.

Note that the difference between *type parameter* and *type argument* is similar to how Java differentiates between a method parameter and argument. When you declare a method as `void bar(Object obj)` the `Object obj` is a parameter. However, when you call the method like `bar(someObjInstance)` the value of `someObjInstance` is the argument.

### Code Examples of the Terminology

Seeing some examples in code can help understand what parts of the code each term applies to.

#### A generic class with type parameters

```java
public class Foo<T extends CharSequence, U> {
    // class body...
}
```

There are two *type parameters*:

1. `T extends Charsequence`

   - The *type variable* is `T`.
   - The *type bounds* are `extends CharSequence`
2. `U`

   - The *type variable* is `U`
   - The *type bounds* are `extends Object` (implicitly defined)

The code looks similar for generic interfaces.

#### A generic method with a type parameter

```java
public void <V extends Number> bar(V obj) {
   // method body...
}
```

This method has one *type parameter*:

1. `V extends Number`

   - The *type variable* is `V`.
   - The *type bounds* are `extends Number`.

The code looks similar for generic constructors.

#### A parameterized type (no wildcard)

```java
public <E extends Number> void bar(List<E> list) {
    // method body...
}
```

There is one *parameterized type*:

1. `List<E>`

   - The *type argument* is `E`.

#### A parameterized type (with wildcard)

```java
public void bar(List<? extends Number> list) {
    // method body...
}
```

There is one *parameterized type*:

1. `List<? extends Number>`

   - The *type argument* is `? extends Number`

### Back to the Rules

As I mentioned, it's important to note that the rules only mention the erasure of *type variables*. The reason this is important is because wildcards are not allowed in the places where *type variables* can be defined (i.e. in *type parameters*). A wildcard can only be used in a *type argument* which is a part of a *parameterized type*.

The erasure of a *parameterized type* is simply the raw type.

---

## When Does Type Erasure Matter?

In everyday development of generic code type erasure is virtually irrelevant. One of the only times you have to know how type erasure works in some detail is when working with *raw types*. In an ideal and just world you'll only work with raw types when working with legacy code (from the days before Java 5) that you cannot change. In other words, unless you're forced to work with raw types you should **always** appropriately use generics.

However, maybe you're forced to work with raw types or you're simply curious. In that case, you need to know how type erasure works because the erasure determines what types are used. Here's an example of a generic class:

```java
public class Foo<T extend CharSequence, U> {

    private List<T> listField;
    private U objField;

    public void bar(List<? extends T> listParam) {
        // method body...
    }

    public U baz(T objParam) {
        // method body...
    }

    public <V extends Number> V qux(V objParam) {
        // method body...
    }

}
```

And following the aforementioned rules of type erasure, here's what the above class looks like afterwards:

```java
// the raw type of Foo
public class Foo {

    private List listField;
    private Object objField;

    public void bar(List listParam) {
        // method body...
    }

    public Object baz(CharSequence objParam) {
        // method body...
    }

    public Number qux(Number objParam) {
        // method body...
    }

}
```

But again, you'll only need to know about the latter version when you're using raw types.

---

## Applying This Knowledge to Your Question

Some of what we've learned so far is that wildcards can only be used in *type arguments* and are thus only applicable to *parameterized types*. The erasure of a *parameterized type* is simply the raw type. If we apply this knowledge to your examples you get the following:

1. Example #1

   - Original

     > ```
     > public static void funcA(List<? extends Number> l)
     > ```
   - Erased

     ```
     public static void funcA(List l)
     ```
2. Example #2

   - Original

     > ```
     > public static void funcB(List<? super Integer> l)
     > ```
   - Erased

     ```
     public static void funcB(List l)
     ```
3. Example #3

   - Original (forgot to specify return type in question, assuming `void`)

     > ```
     > public static <T extends Integer> void funcC(List<? extends T> l)
     > ```
   - Erased

     ```
     public static void funcC(List l)
     ```
4. Example #4

   - Original

     > ```
     > public static <T extends Integer> void funcC(List<T> l)
     > ```
   - Erased

     ```
     public static void funcC(List l)
     ```

### Reinforcing the Point

To really point out the difference between the erasure of a *type variable* and the erasure of a *parameterized type* let's look at another example.

```java
public class Foo<T extends Number> {

    public void bar(T obj) {
        // method body...
    }

    public void baz(List<? extends T> list) {
        // method body...
    }

}
```

The method `bar` has a single parameter of type `T`. The parameter is using the *type variable* directly. The erasure of a *type variable* is the erasure of its leftmost bound which is `Number` in this case. This means after erasure the method's parameter is `Number`.

The method `baz` has a single parameter of type `List<? extends T>`. Here, the *type variable* `T` is being used as the upper bound in the *type argument* of a *parameterized type*. In other words, despite a *type variable* being used, the erasure actually being used here is that of a *parameterized type*. This means after erasure the method's parameter is just `List`. This would happen even if the *type argument* was a lower-bounded wildcard (e.g. `List<? super T>`), an unbounded wildcard (e.g. `List<?>`), or even a non-wildcard (e.g. `List<T>`).

### How Wildcards are Handled by Type Erasure

To directly answer your question on how type erasure treats wildcards, the answer is effectively: **It doesn't, not directly**. Wildcards simply disappear (when the *parameterized type* is erased) and have no significance in the resulting raw type.

Wildcards enable flexibility for those using the generic API. Here are some Q&As which address that concept:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)
- [Difference between `<? super T>` and `<? extends T>` in Java [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)
- [What is the use and point of unbound wildcards generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671072/what-is-the-use-and-point-of-unbound-wildcards-generics-in-java)

Hopefully those Q&As also help answer your auxiliary question, which is what are the differences between the second and fourth examples from your post.

Comment: holly molly this is one seriously awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 is saying that you can pass `List<? super Integer>`, so a `List<Integer>` is ok, but also `List<Number>` or `List<Object>`.

The next example however says you can pass `List<? extends T>` where `<T extends Integer>`. So really you can only pass `List<Integer>` and if they existed any subclass of `Integer` (which don't exist because `Integer` is final).

As you can see they are quite the opposite of each other.

The last example is sort of similar. You are not specifically using `T` anywhere else, so it is resolving to the same thing. This would be more useful if you needed `T` as an extra parameter or part of the return value.

Finally don't get confused about the role of type erasure. The `?` is a generic type wildcard, nothing related to type erasure.

Type erasure is just the fact that at runtime *generic types* do not exist during execution. Generics only enforce compile time checks. After compilation you will just have a plain List.

Comment: i need time to understand your response. But two days ago i asked a question and according the response their, it seems that erasure exist also in compile time (changing method signature): _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549511/how-erasure-of-generics-replace-multiple-bounds/58549819?noredirect=1#comment103421693_58549819_

Comment: Well yes, after compilation generics do not exist. That is what I meant by it only occurs at runtime. Generics are only a compile time check to reduce mistakes. After compilation every `List<T>` becomes just `List` etc.

Comment: @jbx the fact that `List<T>` is erased to `List` _does_ not mean that generics to do exist after compilation. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57102366/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene that is precisely what i said. "after compilation generics do not exist" Read my comments!

Comment: @jbx well in my understanding _Type erasure is just the fact that at runtime generic types do not exist during execution_ means that generics completely do not exist at runtime - and they do, if you would also read my linked answer. This is just nitpicking, I guess, because everyone thinks that they don't exist, at all.